# Git, Init remote repository

Tags: git, version-control

we are changing our VCS from Subversion to Git. Server is installed and running so far now to get things done right: If I create a local repo on my machine and want to push/clone this to a remote repository (a central server - in this case) - I have to do a `git --bare init project.git` on the remote server, is this right? Is there a possibility to create the remote repo without to logging into the central machine in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some kind of git server that allows this to happen. I have a patched version of gitosis on my github account that allows you to setup wildcard entries so this will work.

https://github.com/mzupan/gitosis

If you follow the readme it will explain how you setup a wildcard entry in the config